# Excel Formula - FORECAST, OFFSET, MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working with a workbook that was provided to me. The issue I'm having is that the below formula references a separate table (Cov. & Ded. Factors) and is adding a 4th decimal place to the factor listed in that table.

The table is structured as the following:

```
Limit   Factor
100000  0.867
105000  0.880
110000  0.893
115000  0.907
120000  0.920
125000  0.933
```

The problem is that if my limit value is 100999, the factor being returned is 0.8696 instead of 0.867. I'm not familiar enough with the functions that were provided to know how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
=IFERROR(FORECAST($D20,OFFSET('Cov. & Ded. Factors'!$B$4:$B$384,MATCH('Rater v2.1'!$D20,'Cov. & Ded. Factors'!$A$4:$A$384,1)-1,0,2),OFFSET('Cov. & Ded. Factors'!$A$4:$A$384,MATCH('Rater v2.1'!$D20,'Cov. & Ded. Factors'!$A$4:$A$384,1)-1,0,2)),"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a round function that you can nest the code in:

```
=round(IFERROR(FORECAST($D20,OFFSET('Cov. & Ded. Factors'!$B$4:$B$384,MATCH('Rater v2.1'!$D20,'Cov. & Ded. Factors'!$A$4:$A$384,1)-1,0,2),OFFSET('Cov. & Ded. Factors'!$A$4:$A$384,MATCH('Rater v2.1'!$D20,'Cov. & Ded. Factors'!$A$4:$A$384,1)-1,0,2)),""), 3)
```

Comment: That does it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a dumb answer, and something you have looked into.

But is only 3 decimal points turned on and the value in the lookup table really 0.8696?